# Serial LED bulb connectivity

Tags: led

some of the LED are on and most of the bulbs are off but i checked individual bulb status with multimeter and those bulbs are in off status are actuallyy good let me know  how to check why the bulbs are not ON 
how to check the connectivity issue

Comment: Add the circuit, and add interpunctuation to make it readable.

Comment: Hi Balu, Are the LEDs connected in series? Are they of one colour or different colours? How many LEDs are there in the string? What is the supply voltage? Is there a current limiting resistor in the string?
A schematic would be of great help in solving your problem.

Comment: If some are on and some are off, then the chances are that they aren't really in series.

Comment: Please show a picture of what you are trying to describe.

Comment: they are in series , they are in different colours green & red

Comment: It contains red & green and are connected series. yesterday i try to check individual led using multimeter and some of the leds are not glowing when i connect the probes to the led legs